# Collapsible subset of partially ordered set

Tags: python, data-structures, set

#### Problem

I am looking for python implementation of a special kind of subset of a partially ordered universal set. It is special because there are restrictions on which elements from the universal set this subset (which I would call *CollapsibleSubset*) can contain. *CollapsibleSubset* has to satisfy 1) *"Collapsibility"* and 2) *"Absence of comparable elements"* requirements. The operations on *CollapsibleSubsets* are also defined differently compared to normal sets. I will illustrate the formal definition with the example of file system paths.

#### Example - File system paths set

Consider a file system tree:

```
/root/
├── dir1/
│   ├── file11.txt
│   └── file12.txt
├── dir2/
│   ├── file21.txt
│   └── file22.txt
└── file0.txt
```

The universal set, in this case, are all valid paths { `/root`, `/root/dir1`, `/root/dir1/file11.txt` .. `/root/file0.txt`}. The partial order `lt` is defined by the directory structure, i.e. `lt(a,b)` means that `b` is an ancestor directory of `a`, e.g. `lt(/root/dir1, /root)` is `True`.

The idea of using *CollapsibleSubset* is to represent a set of paths in the briefest way, i.e. with a few elements as possible. E.g. `CollapsibleSubset({/root/dir1, /root/dir2})` would represent all files and dirs in `dir1`, `dir2`.

#### Definition

*CollapibleSubset* **A** of a partially-ordered set **U**, is a set of elements from **U** that satisfies two requirements:

1. "Collapsibility".

   [image]

   , where *dp* is a direct predecessor relation:  [image]

   In other words, if all predecessors of an element belong to the subset, then the element itself must belong to the subset.

   **Example.** `{root/dir1/file11.txt, /root/dir1/file12.txt}` is not a valid CollapibleSubset, but `{/root/dir1}` is.
2. No comparable elements

   [image]

   In other words, if an element belongs to the subset, none of its predecessors can.

   **Example.** `{/root/dir1, /root/dir1/file12.txt}` is not a valid CollapibleSubset, but `{/root/dir1}` is.

Requirements 1 and 2 ensure that the subset contains as few elements as possible.

##### Operations

**Union**

A,B - CollapsibleSubsets, C=Union(A,B) if C is a valid CollapsibleSubset and:

[image]

**Example.**

```
CollapsibleSubset({'/root/dir1', '/root/dir2/file21.txt'}).union(
    CollapsibleSubset({'/root/dir2/file22.txt', '/root/file0.txt'}
) = CollapsibleSubset({'/root'})
```

**Complement**

A - CollapsibleSubset, B = Complement(A) if B is a valid CollapsibleSubset and:

[image]

**Example.**

```
CollapsibleSubset({'/root/dir2/file21.txt'}).complement()=
CollapsibleSubset({'/root/dir1', '/root/dir2/file22.txt', '/root/file0.txt'}))
```

#### Possible CollapsibleSubset creation API

Partial order in practice can be specified by supremum and a function that returns direct predecessors. For the paths set example:

```
>>> colsub = CollapsibleSubset(sup='/root', pred_func=lambda p: os.listdir(p), elements={'/root/dir1', '/root/file0'})
```

#### Another use-case - arbitrary hierarchy subset

The file system example is not my only use-case for which having a `CollapsibleSubset` class would be useful. Another one is defining a subset of an arbitrary hierarchy in the fastest way.

**Example.**
Having the following hierarchy:

```
                Commit
             /     |    \
           /      Fix     \
         /       /   \      \
  Feature   CodeFix  DocFix  Refactoring
   /          /        \           \
 ....       ....       ....        ...
```

defined as a dictionary:

```
>>> hierarchy = {'Commit': ['Feature', 'Fix', 'Refactoring'], 'Fix': ['CodeFix', 'DocFix'], ...}
```

I would like to define a subset of it in the briefest way. For example, a way to define all types of commits that are different kinds of fixes or refactorings with *CollapsibleSubset* would be:

```
>>> CollapsibleSubset('Commit', lambda p: hierarchy[p], {'Fix', 'Refatoring'})
```

#### Question

Is such *CollapsibleSubset* abstraction already implemented in any library?

Comment: I don't think all your formal definitions make sense, but if U is a known directory tree, then `type CollapsibleSubset = Map<String, CollapsibleSubset> | ALL_DESCENDENTS` seems to work fine.  The elements of the subset are the paths from the root to ALL_DESCENDENTS.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about such abstraction butwe can write it by ourselves.
First we need some structure to store the order and helpful information:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children=None, name=""):
        self.parent = None  # parent Node
        self.dotted_name = name  # full name with dots separated elements
        self.name = name
        self.children = {c.name: c for c in children or []}
        for c in self.children.values():
            c.parent = self
            c.dotted_name = f"{self.name}.{c.name}" if self.name else c.name
        self.taken = set()  # Set of already taken children for specific node
        self.locked = False  # Indicates that some of parent is already taken
        self.marked = (
            False  # Used in complement to mark all Nodes that have children already in Set
        )

    def add_to_non_locked(self, name):
        if not self.locked:
            self.taken.add(name)

    @property
    def is_complete(self):
        return len(self.taken) == len(self.children)  # We should collapse here

    def change_lock(self, val):
        """ Change locked attribute recursively """
        self.locked = val
        for c in self.children.values():
            c.change_lock(val)

    def clear(self):
        """ Clear Node and children, used in collapse """
        self.taken.clear()
        for c in self.children.values():
            c.clear()

    def mark(self, mark_parent=True, mark_children=True):
        """ Used in complement """
        if self.marked:
            return
        self.marked = True
        if self.parent and mark_parent:
            self.parent.mark(mark_children=False)
        if mark_children:
            for c in self.children.values():
                c.mark(mark_parent=False)

    def get_non_marked(self):
        """ Traverse every Node and take non marked which is what complement should returs """
        if not self.marked:
            res = [self]
        else:
            res = [x for c in self.children.values() for x in c.get_non_marked()]
        self.marked = False
        return res

    def __str__(self):
        ll = [str(c) for c in self.children.values()]
        return f"{self.name}{ll if ll else ''}"


# Creates example structure
f11 = Node(name="f11")
f12 = Node(name="f12")
f21 = Node(name="f21")
f22 = Node(name="f22")
dir1 = Node({f11, f12}, name="dir1")
dir2 = Node({f21, f22}, name="dir2")
file0 = Node(name="file0")
root = Node({dir1, dir2, file0})
```

Now it's time to proper set:

```
class CollapsibleSubset(set):
    def __init__(self, *args, root: Node, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

    def add_el(self, el: list):
        """ Assuming element to add is in form list of elements """
        last = self.get_node(el).parent
        last.add_to_non_locked(el[-1])
        if last.is_complete:
            for t in last.taken:
                self.discard(
                    ".".join([*el[:-1], t])
                )  # Removing all elements from set as we need to collapse
            last.clear()
            last.change_lock(True)
            self.add_el(el[:-1])  # Running recursively for parent
            return
        self.add(".".join(el))

    def union(self, other):
        for el in other:
            self.add_el(el.split("."))

    def complement(self):
        for el in self:
            self.get_node(el).mark()
        x = self.root.get_non_marked()
        return CollapsibleSubset([a.dotted_name for a in x], root=deepcopy(root))

    def get_node(self, el):
        if isinstance(el, str):
            el = el.split(".")
        return reduce(lambda x, y: getattr(x, "children")[y], el, self.root)


s = CollapsibleSubset(root=deepcopy(root))
s2 = CollapsibleSubset(root=deepcopy(root))
s.add_el(["dir1", "f11"])
s2.add_el(["dir1", "f12"])
s2.add_el(["dir2", "f21"])
s.union(s2)
print(s) # CollapsibleSubset({'dir2.f21', 'dir1'})
sc = s.complement()
print(sc) # CollapsibleSubset({'dir2.f22', 'file0'})
```

Let me know if there is something I should explain further.